# Wrong end date for Google calendar recurring event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm wondering if Google has changed something in the calendar API or I'm just nuts... When I look at the data exported for a recurring event, the "end" "dateTime" for the event is the last date of the series. Unless I'm nuts, previously, this value was the end date/time of the first instance of the event. I can manipulate the date so my software is not longer broken, but there is no way that I did not notice this problem before - something got changed I'm pretty sure.

Sample json extracted from Google:

```
    "start":    {
        "dateTime": "2018-11-26T13:30:00-05:00",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    "end":  {
        "dateTime": "2018-12-14T14:30:00-05:00",
        "timeZone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    "recurrence":   ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181128T055959Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
```

Comment: Can you show your code to create events?

Comment: I'm not trying to create events, just parse calendar data for events that were created by the Google calendar interface. I've posted a snippet.  See how the end date is 18 days after the start?  This is for a weekly recurring event.  Each instance of the event is supposed to be from 13:30 to 14:30. Note: I cannot reproduce this problem with my own account.  The data was obtained from a customer.  So perhaps this is an isolated failure, or I don't understand something about how the event was created.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving recurring events with [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) gives you the end time of the singles event specified by `eventId`, rather than the final data of the recurrence.

Indeed, your line

```
["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181128T055959Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR...
```

contains `UNTIL=20181128T055959Z` - showing that the end date for the recurrence is `28th of November 2018`, which is before

```
"end":  {
        "dateTime": "2018-12-14T14:30:00-05:00", ...}
```

The only reasonable explanation is that during event creation the `14 of December 2018` was erroneously specified as the end date of a single event occurrence - this is not the end date for recurrences.